# Edition based redifinition query

Tags: oracle

I am exploring use of Oracle EBR in for hot patching of our application database. I have searched in Google regarding EBR. What I understand is that EBR will allow user to have many versions of same DB object like PL/SQL procedure etc. User will be able to access a new version when it is enabled for that particular user and the transition will be seamless for existing user i.e. existing sessions will be unaffected. But I am not able to understand how it will not affect the existing sessions. For example if user "X" is in middle of a transaction that uses a DB session and a new EBR version is enabled for that user, won't it affect the current DB session? or will the current DB session won't see the existing EBR and only new sessions will see the new version. Please let me know your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An edition is enabled at the session level not at the user level.  If user X has a dozen sessions, each of those sessions could be using a different edition.

It really wouldn't make sense to try to change the edition the session is using in the middle of a transaction.  I can't imagine why you'd want to try.  And I'd wager heavily that it wouldn't work.

If you're using edition-based redefinition, you would realistically enable the new edition for new sessions or between transactions in a particular session.  Commonly, you'd do a rolling upgrade where each application server gets rebooted and the connection pool set to use the new edition while the connection pools on the other servers remain using the old edition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If the server has to get rebooted for the connection pool to use new edition, doesn't it defeat the purpose of EBR which claims to provide "online" patching. Also DBA who will enable an edition will not be knowing if any user is in middle of a transaction or not.

Comment: @user2032118 - If you're at the point of using EBR, you'd generally have a large number of application servers.  Taking one out of the pool, changing the connection pool to use the new edition, and then putting it back in the pool shouldn't affect the uptime of the application.  That's not the only way to deploy a new edition, just one common choice.  The DBA can create as many editions as they'd like while transactions are taking place.  Again, it's up to each session to determine which edition to use and to change at an appropriate moment.